# mkpath File::Path does not seem to work as expected

Tags: perl, file, dir

I am using mkpath to create a directory.

```
mkpath('/home/myhome') or die "Create of directory  failed: $!";
```

This works if the directory does not exists, yet fails if it does exist.
From the perldocs it said it was similar to mkdir -p unix. However, that command does not fail if directory already exists.

What should I be looking at to create a directory with multiple paths quietly?
v5.8.8

Comment: I do care. I just want error quiesced for directory already existing. I understand I can always code around it, but if there is another function or method that already has this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkpath` throws an exception on error, so you want the following:

```
mkpath('/home/myhome');
```

If you want a custom message, you can use the following:

```
eval { mkpath('/home/myhome'); 1 }
   or die "Can't create home directory: $@\n";
```

Note the use of `$@`, not `$!`.

Answer (score 1):

The [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) says:

> The function returns the list of directories actually created during
>   the call; in scalar context the number of directories created.

as ikdegami pointed out the next error handling will not works

```
mkpath($path) or print "Error creating $path\n" unless -d $path;
```

because the mkpath will croak on fatal errors. (with [Carp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp)), so it will terminate the execution sooner as the error message could be printed.

... unless the execution of `mkpath` is trapped in an eval block. (see [ikegami's anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851208/632407))

Capturing with the eval, would return only one error. e.g:

```
eval { mkpath($p2, $p3); 1 } or die "Can't create home directory: $@\n";
```

if both `$p1` and `$p2` fails - will not report all errors. For print out all errors, you can use an custom variable to store the diagnostics messages, See the doc's [ERROR HANDLING](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html#ERROR-HANDLING) part

In this case, the mkpath will not croak, and in case of fatal error will returns the number of successfully created directories (in scalar context), like:

```
mkpath($path1, $path2 , {error => \my $err});
```

from the doc:

> Note that if no errors are encountered, $err will reference an empty
>   array. This means that $err will always end up TRUE; so you need to
>   test @$err to determine if errors occured.

And you can print them out all, see the example in the doc.

Comment: I like the unless over my if.

Comment: So I still have to wrap the call in an if  -d $path. If it exists, do not attempt to create in an eval block.
if (!(-d $path)) {
mkpath($path) #just use mkpaths error
}

Comment: @Paul the simplest way is what ikegami answered. Just accept his answer. ;)